# Submitting a HTML form using slider as user input and using its data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a slider to set a pulse time using HTML and I need to submit the data to a java function for which I am using an HTML Form. Currently, the scenario is my controller fetches the data `onchange` whereas I want it to fetch data only `onsubmit` also it should view the range set by slider before submitting.

> HTML Code:

```
<tr height=40>
    <td width=40></td>
        <td>
        <label for="P1_pulsetime">PORT 1 PULSE TIME</label>
        <form id="P1_pulsetime" onsubmit="">
            <input type="range" min="10" max="120" value="20" class="slider" id="pulse_time_1" onchange="Port1_pulsetime()" required/>
            <div>20</div><button type="submit" formaction="Port1_pulsetime()" >PORT 1 PULSE</button>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

> JavaScript:

```
function Port1_pulsetime(){
        if(connected_flag==1){
            client.subscribe("lazy/test");
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("pulse_time_1").value);
            message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
            client.send(message);
            }
            else {
                console.log("not connected")
            }
        return false;
    }
```

> Slider event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
        var rng = document.querySelector("input");
        var listener = function() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = rng.value;
            });
        };

        rng.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
            listener();
        rng.addEventListener("mousemove", listener);
        });
        rng.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        rng.removeEventListener("mousemove", listener);
        });

        // include the following line to maintain accessibility
        // by allowing the listener to also be fired for
        // appropriate keyboard events
        rng.addEventListener("keydown", listener);

        });
```

Comment: you may need to remove onchange="Port1_pulsetime" from <input> tag

Comment: yes i tried that and used onsubmit in button instead, but it didn't worked.

Comment: i tested your code by making some changes
i think the issue is with your custom code. 
if(connected_flag==1){
            client.subscribe("lazy/test");
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("pulse_time_1").value);
            message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
            client.send(message);
            }

if you remove all these and keep an alert action inside this function, its returning the correct value. check if your custom code is working fine.
if you want , i would add the code i used to test by removing some of your custom code

Comment: Yes, my custom code is working fine it is fetching correct data onchange and working properly ,all i need is to fetch data on submitting through button  and need to display the range before submitting so that user can set according to there requirement.

Comment: ok remove on change from input and replace formaction with onclick="Port1_pulsetime()"

Comment: Did the same, but no changes observed,its working the same way as before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This solution worked for me.but now as soon as I submit the pulse time my connection with server is lost though my cloud receives the data successfully and acts accordingly after re-connection with server.

## HTML CODE

```
<tr height=40>
    <td width=40></td>
        <td>
        <form id="P1_pulsetime" onsubmit="Port1_pulsetime()">
            <br><br>
            <span id="slider_value" style="color:red;"></span>
            10<input type="range" id="P1_PT" min="10" max="120" value="20" name="Port 1 pulse time" onchange="show_value(this.value);" required/>120
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Port 1 pulse">
            <br>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

## JavaScript

```
function show_value(x){
        document.getElementById("slider_value").innerHTML=x;
    }

function Port1_pulsetime(){
        if(connected_flag==1){
            client.subscribe("lazy/test");
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("P1_PT").value);
            message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
            client.send(message);
            }
            else {
                console.log("not connected")
            }
        return false;
    }
```